# Why Dates appearing differently when opened in .CSV file

Tags: c#, regex

I have hundreds of lines of data from a text file which is captured using Regex MatchCollection and outputting the same to as a comma demlimited (csv) file for subsequent examination in excel.

My Regex Expression is as follows:-

```
Regex Line3 = new Regex(@"(?<one>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{1,20}114B\s{1,15}(?<two>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<three>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<four>\d{1,11})\s{1,30}(?<five>\d{1,11})");//<one> catpures the date data.

MatchCollection matches = Line3.Matches(line1);
foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Writer1.WriteLine("")//
    //Writer1.Write(line1.Substring(1, 27) + ","); //Do not consider this.
    Writer1.Write(m.Groups["one"].Value + ",");
    Writer1.Write(m.Groups["two"].Value + ",");
    Writer1.Write(m.Groups["three"].Value + ",");
    Writer1.Write(m.Groups["four"].Value + ",");
    Writer1.Write(m.Groups["five"].Value + ",");
 }
```

My tex file will always contain uniform data that matches with the Regular Expression and my programme is beautifully capturing the required information thanks to the Regular Expressions designers genius.

But when I open the csv file in excel (double clicking the .csv), the column containing the date data appears irregularly like below.

```
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0, //appears right-aligned in excel.
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0, //this is how it looks like in Editpad Lite.
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0, // these dashes appears in excel as as 12/4/2012
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0, //next five lines as well.
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0,
  12-04-2012,0,0,0,0, //
  12-04-2012,5467,757488,846815,0,
 13-04-12,0,0,0,0, //appears left aligned in excel.
 13-04-12,0,0,0,0,
 20-04-12,0,0,500,0,
 21-04-12,1740,17905,17900,0,
 21-04-12,0,0,0,0,
 24-04-12,1466,31666,31420,0,
```

My input file looks like.

```
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
12-04-12                  114B        5467        757488         846815                0
13-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
13-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
20-04-12                  114B           0             0            500                0
21-04-12                  114B        1740         17905          17900                0
21-04-12                  114B           0             0              0                0
24-04-12                  114B        1466         31666          31420                0
```

The output is very much uniform when I examined the .csv file with notepad. The problem crops up only whe I open the csv file in excel.

Could anyone of you help solve the reason for the inconsistency?.

Comment: what is the proper output you get in text file ?

Comment: In the output .csv file (if I open with notepad), it appears as 01-12-13.which is in dd-MM-yy format. Always. The trouble is in excel when opened double clicking csv file.

Comment: You need to provide input string for problematic line, say 3/5/2012 ... give the full input line for that

Comment: All input lines are in the same format ie. like 12-12-12 always there is no input problematic line in the file as the text file itself is uniform computer output from a database.

Comment: You needed to follow proper guideline of asking question, you haven't provided any sample output string, rather coming up with how the output appears in excel... the lines that are comming up differently in csv didn't appear like that without any reason, and for that you need to put the out strings that you print in file.... if you are sure that everything is fine then no point asking question

Comment: Can you pinpoint pattern of mismatching, for example is it adding same number of days or adding digit to days starting with zero?

Comment: I have included the full string appears in the csv file. Please note that I opend it in text mode and cut out those to update my question as per the suggestion of @Maverick_Mrt. There is not pattern mismatching because I am getting all the required data.@oNerd

Comment: You should change your CSV generation code to output in ISO-8601 format to remove any ambiguity. "`dd-MM-yy`" is one of the worst date formats you chould choose!

Comment: There are two steps in what you are doing. First the C# code with regular expression that writes to a CSV file. Second reading the CSV in Excel. You have only shown two lines of the initial input plus several lines of the final output. You need to [edit] your question to show the intermediate CSV file. More than that, you need to [edit] the question to show three things: (1) some input lines, (2) the CSV (open it in Notepad) and (3) the way it is shown in Excel.

Comment: I have further expanded the input and output so far as to give you a clear picture of what they look like as suggested @AdrianHHH. The programe only writer to the csv file. Later I manually open up the csv file interactively. In India and Pakistan, the date format is in dd-MM-yy.format.

Comment: The correct thing to do would be write out the dates as yyyy-MM-dd so that there is no ambiguity. As it, Excel is parsing dates as MM-dd-yyyy when it can, and doing nothing when it can't.

Comment: But how come excel treat the same data differently. There is an inherent flaw in excel in that case. I am giving to excel uniform data.@AdrianHHH. @Andrew Morton.

Comment: Excel assumes dates are in the format set in Windows regional settings. If it can parse a string to a date using those settings, it will. You cannot simply assume that all the computers that load your output text file have their regional settings set to what you hope if you want it to be reliable.

Comment: @Dai suggested that ISO-8601 should be adopted. I have no choice myself. I am, in this case, doing data processing of somebody else's file. When I do the processing I should present the output in the format most acceptable in India. The processed output is also not meant for internal audience but for home consumption where YYYY-MM-DD format will slow their reading prowess.

Comment: I said, open the CSV file in Notepad and show us what that file contains. You appear to have misunderstood the two stage nature of what you are doing and the need to show the intermediate stage.

Comment: No I have understood correctly. I opend it in Editpad Lite. That is what is available in that file which is given as output file. Thank you.@AdrianHHH

Comment: @Unnikrishnan if the output file that you have shared is what is seen in your question, then how come 12/4/2012 appears there ? As per your regex it only contain dd-mm-yy, then where did those slashes appear from ?

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt. What I have posted is correct. I under stand a regex coined to catpure like @"[0-9]{2]-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" can capture only 12-12-12 like formats. In the output text file also, it appears correctly. You will appreciate the fact when I output it csv file (it is text file with .csv exttension) using StreamReader, it correctly comes. When I open the .csv file double clicking it, you know it will automatically open in excel. In my case I am using Excel 2016. The '/' appears only in excel. How what is in excel changes to '/' in some cases I don't know. Hope you got my point. Thanks.

Comment: Your question states *"when I open the csv file in excel ... the column containing the date data appears irregularly like below"* this suggests that all the data is shown in one column and that the commas have not been interpreted as column separators. When I run your code (after filling in the important bits you omitted all of the output lines match `^\d\d-04-12,`. None of the lines include a `/`. Your previous comment says you *"output it csv file ... using StreamReader"* which cannot work. You could output using `StreamWriter`.

Comment: I am sorry about the error. I use StreamReader to read a file and use the Regex MatchCollection to capture the data which is written using StreamWriter. I am extremely sorry about the error. You know getting mired in some issue but nevertheless without being able to achieve the desired result makes me mad. But I am nearer to a solution today morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you output the dates in yyyy-MM-dd format then Excel should parse them as dates.

You can do that by converting the text dd-MM-yy into a DateTime using an appropriate CultureInfo, it is then easy to write out the date in yyyy-MM-dd format.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string inFile = @"C:\temp\sampledata.txt";
            string outFile = @"C:\temp\sampledata.csv";

            //<one> catpures the date data:
            Regex re = new Regex(@"(?<one>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{1,20}114B\s{1,15}(?<two>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<three>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<four>\d{1,11})\s{1,30}(?<five>\d{1,11})");

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(inFile))
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outFile))
                {
                    string line1;
                    DateTime dt;
                    var ci = new CultureInfo("ur-PK");
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        line1 = sr.ReadLine();
                        MatchCollection matches = re.Matches(line1);
                        foreach (Match m in matches)
                        {
                            dt = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["one"].Value, ci);
                            sw.Write(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ",");
                            sw.Write(m.Groups["two"].Value + ",");
                            sw.Write(m.Groups["three"].Value + ",");
                            sw.Write(m.Groups["four"].Value + ",");
                            sw.Write(m.Groups["five"].Value + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used "ur-PK" as you mentioned that your input file date format is what is used in India and Pakistan, but there are several -IN codes to choose from and I do not know if one of them could be incorrect for your use.

Output using the sample data you showed:

```
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,0,0,0,0
2012-04-12,5467,757488,846815,0
2012-04-13,0,0,0,0
2012-04-13,0,0,0,0
2012-04-20,0,0,500,0
2012-04-21,1740,17905,17900,0
2012-04-21,0,0,0,0
2012-04-24,1466,31666,31420,0
```

When you open the csv file in Excel, it *should* recognise "2012-04-12" etc. as dates regardless of the Windows date format settings. I do not have Excel to test with.

It *should* then display the dates in the Windows short date format setting.

Comment: This is likely a good solution. I am just experimenting what you have done before coming back to you.

Comment: @Unnikrishnan I do not have much hope for this idea after trying the csv on Excel on my phone, but it might be that Excel 2016 does a better job. It may be that you have to set the locale correctly in Windows.

Comment: Morton 's observation is correct. I tested Morton's programme. And finds that if I open the file in excel I will get it in the format of dd/MM/yyyy format in my computer. This may vary depending Regional Settings.

Comment: I meant I will get it in MM/dd/yyy format in my computer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the problem solved, the considered the view expressed my others especially of Andrew Morton.

This is the method I adopted to solve and get it right in excel.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO; //for StreamReader and StreamWriter
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Globalization; //from two digit date to four digit date conversion.

namespace Experiment2
{
    class DemandRefundOnly
    {
      public line1 {get; set;}
      public Line3 {get; set;}
      DateTime dateTime;
      int FourDigitYear; 
      int Month; 
      int Day;
      DateTime dateTime;
      Regex Line3 = new Regex(@"(?<one>[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})\s{1,20}114B\s{1,15}(?<two>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<three>\d{1,11})\s{1,15}(?<four>\d{1,11})\s{1,30}(?<five>\d{1,11})");//Regex to capture data. //<one> catpures the date data.

      //Only the relevant date part is going to be shown in the output given.

      using (StreamReader Reader1 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\UK\data.txt"))
      { //StreamREader to read the input text file.
         using(StreamWriter Writer1 = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Sample.csv"))
         { //StreamWriter to wrie to the output file.
            while((line1 = Reader1.ReadLine())!= null)
            { //to loop through the input file.
               MatchCollection matches = Line3.Matches(line1);
               foreach (Match m in matches)
               { //for...each to loop through and print the matches.
                  //Writer1.Write(m.Groups["one"].Value + ","); //this line modified with the following.


                 Day = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["one"].Value.Substring(0, 2));
                    //the above captures the first two digits date string contained in m.Groups["one"].Value and stores the first two characters as int to Day.
                 Month = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["one"].Value.Substring(3, 2));
                 FourDigitYear = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups["one"].Value.Substring(6, 2));
                 FourDigitYear = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.ToFourDigitYear(FourDigitYear);
                 dateTime = new DateTime(FourDigitYear, Month, Day);
                 Writer1.WriteLine(dateTime);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The outputput file written to with StreamWriter will look like.

```
4/5/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/5/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/9/2012 12:00:00 AM
4/12/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

I tried importing the newly created output file into Excel (wherein in one column) dates appears correctly all in a uniform manner. This is acceptable to me since we in India uses slash or dash or even dot to separate dd mm yy. This is okay for me. I also acknowledge the fact that I got the FourDigit Converter code line from Stackoverflow itself. Special acknowlegement to @AdrianHHH and @Andrew Morten who actively spent certain amount of their valuable time for me.

Comment: The dates are appearing uniformly in csv file. I checked 1020 entries I wrote to the csv file. It also appears that I can remove the time part from the date by using ToShortDateString();